# How to dynamically determine the Class a List must contains

Tags: java, list, generics, reflection

I wrote a generic method, but I don't know how to programmatically tell the `List` the kind of objects it must contain.

I read that I can't know the `<T>` object class, so I added another parameter (returnClass) to the method.

```
public <T extends IModel> List<T> getIModel(Cursor cursor, Class<T> returnClass){

   //returnClass is the class that List must contains.

   //I need something like this
   List<returnClass.getClass()> list = new ArrayList<>();   
   list.add(new Photo());  

}
```

these are my "model" class

```
public class Media implements IModel{}

public class Photo extends Media{}
```

I cannot do this:

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();  
list.add(new Photo());
```

since `List<T>` determine just that the `List` is a `List` of object that extends `IModel` and I'll get an error when doing `list.add(new Photo())`, because the `List` is expecting T and I'm adding `Photo`.

What I need is determine what subclass of `Imodel` put inside the `List`.

Comment: List< T > list;

Comment: No. Because I won't be able to do list.add(subclass). List<T> determine just that the List is a List of object that extends IModel. What I need is determine what subclass of Imodel put inside the List

Comment: you're gonna have to cast like `list.add((T)(new Photo())`. btw it's bad code; try to rethink your design.

Comment: I edited my post to explain better

Comment: How do you call your `getIModel()` method? E.g. `List<Photo> photos = getIModel(cursor, Photo.class);` and in some other place `List<Audio> audios = getIModel(cursor, Audio.class);` ? Of course, for the second usage it would be illegal to do `list.add(new Photo());` inside your method, and that's what the compiler complains about.

Comment: It does not make sense.  Assume you have anther `Media` child class `Music`, and you are calling `getIModel(cursor, Music.class)`, how can it be correct for you to add a `Photo` to a `List<Music>`?  Double think what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like:

```
public <T extends IModel> List<T> getIModel(Cursor cursor){
    List<T> t = new ArrayList<T>();
    return t;
}
```

Ps. You don't need `Class<T> returnClass`.

and to get the type of list you can check the first element:

```
if(list.size()==0){
  // any type
} else if(if(list.get(0) instanceof Photo){
  // you can insert only the Photo
} else if(...){
  // do some stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the solution similar to mine. I hope there was a more "dinamic" solution. Thank you :)

Comment: @MDP how about `public class Photo extends Media implements IModel` and then you can add like this `list.add((T) photo);`

Comment: @MDP, ok I aggre with you it is bad code. This is how you can do it with good code `public <T extends Media & IModel> List<T> getIModel(Cursor cursor, Class<T> returnClass){....}`